# Solspace Search and Low Events

Tags: solspace, supersearch, low-events

I am using Low Events and Solspace search and need a way of searching through Events by month and/or year.
Where do i begin when searching through my low events field?

I realise i can use low search and will have to if there is no way, but i am already using solspace search so ideally would like to know if its possible.

My form currently has the following fields:

- Keywords
- Month
- Year
- Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Super Search cannot search directly in the low_events database table, nor can it use the JSON encoded data in the native channel_entries table. If you need to combine Low Events with a search, you'll have to use Low Search.

Comment: Yeah, if it is possible then i cant figure out how.

Comment: @Low Is data stored only in exp_channel_data or in a separate table? Couldn't the `third_party_search_index()` method be added to Low Events to it work in Super Search and elsewhere? Ref: http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/third_party_support/

Comment: @Zenbuman: the `third_party_search_index` method is used for *keyword searches only*. If you want to limit a search to "events of a given month", that's not a keyword search, but a targeted filter (custom query). LE saves data in its own table, but also keeps a copy of that data in the channel_data table, json_encoded.